# How do I use `window.external.Tampermonkey.openOptions`?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am doing some research on how Greasyfork detect whether a script is installed or not. After doing some debugging and searching, I noticed that Greasyfork can access certain API via `window.external.Tampermonkey`, including:

- `getVersion`: `(<callback>) => undefined`, gets Tampermonkey version info
- `isInstalled`: `(<script name>, <namespace>, <callback>) => undefined`, check if a script is installed and its version
- `openOptions`: `(<param1>, <param2>) => ?`, open option page (options.html)?

> References:
>
> 1. https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/322#issuecomment-252505959
> 2. https://github.com/erosman/support/issues/582#issuecomment-1658350841

The first two methods are simple enough for me to work out their usage, but I can't find information on the usage of the third one. And the obfuscated code surely is not friendly for debugging. My test indicated that you can pass **hash as the first parameter**, and Tampermonkey would open that page successfully. For example:

```js
window.external.Tampermonkey.openOptions("nav=help"); // * Tampermonkey opens the help page.
window.external.Tampermonkey.openOptions("nav=<script id>+settings"); // * Tampermonkey opens the script settings page
```

But I don't know what **the second parameter** is. And is it possible to **pass script name and namespace as parameters** to open that script's settings page?

Comment: It opens TM's dashboard and the parameter is the URL hash part, which you can see in the address bar when you navigate the dashboard sub-pages. I don't know if there's a way to calculate the internal id of the script used in the hash so you can try debugging the code of Tampermonkey in devtools and find out yourself.

Comment: I tried to debug it, but the code is really too messy for me. Any idea on the second param?

Comment: It's not sent to the background, meaning it doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: But if you pass something solid other than an Node as the second param, it would throw an error (`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'initMutationEvent' on 'MutationEvent': parameter 4 is not of type 'Node'.`).  It shows that TM has something like `if (param2)` in the code, but forgot to check if it is a Node, and param2 is actually used (thus an error is issued).

Comment: Since nodes cannot be transferred to the background script and a DOM node is entirely unrelated to the TM's options page, it means this parameter serves no purpose. The most likely reason it's an oversight.